# Why does my jquery ajax post succeed but the $_POST array is still empty?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my first question on here, please bear with me:

**My ajax request is:**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"http://localhost/folder/something.php", 
data: { BuildingName:'Jacaranda'},
success: function(data){alert("It worked")},
error: function(data){alert("It failed")},
}); 
</script>
```

In my something.php file I have:

```
$Building= $_POST['BuildingName']; //Error Occurs Here
```

I get an error on this line stating:
Notice: Undefined index: BuildingName.
When I do VAR_DUMP it returns the $_POST array as empty.
I have checked and rechecked. Looked at different answers here and cannot seem to find the problem. I hope it is not staring me in the face. 
I appreciate any help, thank you.

**SOLUTION:**
 Instead of simply trying to pass data between pages solely which I do not think is possible(correct me if I'm wrong), there has to be an intermediary. I passed my data into MySQL and had my webpage "listen" to the DB and do something based on the most recent entry.

**SOLUTION USING SESSIONS** per the advice of Lukas1 (you're right this is more efficient.)

```
           <?php
                $_SESSION['Building']= 'something';
                $Building= $_SESSION['Building'];

                echo "<script> $('#Jacaranda').click(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $Building= id;
                }) </script>";

            ?>
```

And my call on the next page is:

```
<?php echo $Building ?>
```

Works perfectly without using database as intermediary.

Comment: Nothing in code shown would be problematic. Show more code context. Inspect actual request also in browser dev tools network to see what is actually sent, status etc. Also explain how you are checking what is dumped

Comment: Why are you using `$.ajax` and not `$.post`

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy - trailing comma in an object literal is not a syntax error in javascript

Comment: check the browser developer tools network tab to check the request is as expected

Comment: @MartinBarker - that would not make any difference. $.post is just a wrapper for $.ajax anyway

Comment: it's a wrapper that preconfigures stuff including making sure the processor for the data `processData` is turned on as the `$.ajaxSetup` could have it turned off by something else before hand

Comment: I used the network tools and found that it posting the data correctly:  array (size=1)
  'BuildingName' => string 'Jacaranda' (length=9) This is good, but I still need to figure out why the next page gives an empty set when getting this data.

Comment: My guess is somehow you are trying to return to that url after the ajax with no post data in the request ... or as shown in network tools the problem doesn't exist

Comment: @KeelanParaja If that's the response (that **is** PHPs `var_dump`) then what's the problem? You're posting and getting the expected result.

Comment: @MartinBarker The [jQuery.post() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) don't seem to indicate anything about `processData`. In fact it states the shorthand to `jQuery.ajax()` with just `type, url, data, success and dataType` attributes. All of those are set in OPs question (or left as default). Where's the info about `processData` coming from? Edit: The [jQuery ajax source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js) (Lines 833-852) define the wrapper, no additional configuration as far as I can see.

Comment: Interestingly using HTML post through <form> works fine. Although the network tools are saying that the correct data is getting sent with ajax request, when the next page is loaded which has the PHP script to grab the data, the var_dump then says empty set. Seems like a behind the scenes issues, something is conflicting.

Comment: @KeelanParaja I think you're confusing your expected result. using ajax does send the request and that's it. Using a form sends the request **and displays the result in the browser**. Your ajax works fine and the result returned works aswell, you're just not doing anything with it (see your "empty" success function).

Comment: @Toastrackenigma The ajax POST is working fine, if OP changed his `success` function to include something like `alert(data);` or `console.log(data);` he would in fact see the PHP output and the var_dump'ed `$_POST` array.

Comment: Yes it is working fine. I think the problem is that by the time I get to the page the data is gone (or something to that effect). Upon a button click my <ahref> takes me to datapage.php, which has an include('something.php') statement. However before I click that button my ajax request sends the data to something.php. So when I click on my button it takes me to a fresh page that no longer has the data because the something.php is refreshed. Is that correct logic? I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: When you load `something.php` again...it is a new instance and the data you sent previously won't be there

Comment: Yes thank you @charlietfl. I overlooked that... thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thank you @ccKep as well. Appreciate the help.

Comment: truth be told I have not studied your problem very well but in your suggested solution you're talking about using database as an intermediary to pass some data between pages. Now, I don't know what kind of data you're passing, but if those data are only relevant for current session, I'd suggest avoid using database for this particular purpose and use `$_SESSION` instead

Comment: @Lukas1 thanks, I added my code above using sessions rather than DB. Works very nicely, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Just change your data attribute to

```
"BuildingName=Jacaranda"
```

and it should work all fine.